# Associating <div class="span4"> with dynamically generated button in jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var showGoals = $('<button>Show Globals</button>').click(function () { alert('hi')});
            var resp1 = $('<button>Show locals</button>').click(function () { alert('hi2')});

            $("#newId").append(showGoals, resp1);
            $("#newId").show();
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="newId" style="display:none"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want the buttons to be encapsulated in div class="span4" and  div class="span12" respectively. Can someone help out. I am new to jQuery.

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking, could you elaborate?

Comment: `I want the buttons to be associated with and receptively`. What does that mean?

Comment: where is the div with the span4 class????

Comment: What's the problem, what are you talking about?  I don't see a `class="span4"` anywhere here.  Also, your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/tEVVF/

Comment: This code make no sense at all.

Comment: @KaranDhamejani: Have you tried anything?  Have you seen jQuery's `.wrap` method?  http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: Do you mean respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this, for example:

```
var showGoals = $('<button>Show Globals</button>').click(function () { alert('hi')});

var showGoalsWrapper = $('<div class="span4"></div>');
showGoalsWrapper.append(showGoals);    

var resp1 = $('<button>Show locals</button>').click(function () { alert('hi2')});

var resp1Wrapper = $('<div class="span12"></div>');
resp1Wrapper.append(resp1);

$("#newId").append(showGoalsWrapper, resp1Wrapper);
$("#newId").show();
```